# Design pattern for Page A waiting for Page B

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I have no idea what this design call.

1. I have a page A, with a Link in it.
2. Click on the link, will open page B in NEW WINDOW/NEW TAB.
3. Page A now shows a 'Waiting for Page B' message.
4. input data in page B, click save, and close page B.
5. page A will notice that page B is closed, and display the input from page B.

I think there is some trigger in page B's unload event, but how does page A notice page B is closed?

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short, you basically need to rely on some server-side operation to manage the "state" between these two pages.

There are a lot of approaches to be taken here, but ultimately, they are going to rely on some form of client-side polling, as an asynchronous event fired from Page B (like your 'Save' operation) won't inherently have the ability to modify the state of Page A upon returning.

Implement a timer in JavaScript to check a server value every few seconds from Page A, and make sure the 'Save' operation from Page B sets that particular condition on the server when it executes.  Page A will detect it and can transition state.

Comment: If you are not too fixated on the whole NEW WINDOW/NEW TAB thing, you could make this whole thing pretty simple by implementing Page B as some kind of Modal Dialog using one of the popular JavaScript UI Libraries like jQueryUI.

Comment: I will rather go with in-page modal dialog - the dialog can use iframe to display another page if needed.

Comment: The case is, my iFrame is as large, like, Google Docs, and won't be closed in a short while.

Answer (score 0):

Try [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).